# Correlated subquery with row number count

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table as follows and what I want is to use get the initial row with least id of each uid group.

The table is as follows

```
_id  uid  type 
1     a    a
2     b    bbb   #satisfied
3     b    ccc
4     b    aaa   #satisfied
5     a    aaa   #satisfied
6     b    eee
```

I can already get the initial row using the following correlated subquery

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE _id IN (
               SELECT MIN(_id) 
               FROM table 
               WHERE type IN ('aaa','bbb')
               GROUP BY uid
             );
```

However, I want the 4th column shown the count of rows satisfied the condition (`type IN ('aaa','bbb')`), as `cnt` shown below:

```
_id  uid  type  cnt
5     a    aaa   1
2     b    bbb   2
```

I think I can count this use several joins and then join the result to my code...But this is ugly...Is there any elegant way to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.cnt
FROM table t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(_id) AS id, COUNT(_id) AS cnt
  FROM table 
  WHERE type IN ('aaa','bbb')
  GROUP BY uid
) t2 ON t1._id = t2.id
ORDER BY t1.uid
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can just use window functions for this:

```
select _id, uid, type, cnt
from (
    select 
        t.*, 
        count(*) over(partition by uid) cnt,
        row_number() over(partition by uid order by _id) rn
    from mytable t
    where type in ('aaa', 'bbb')
) t
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a subquery.  In MySQL 8+, you can use this logic:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MIN(_id) OVER (PARTITION BY uid) as _id,
       uid,
       FIRST_VALUE(type) OVER (PARTITION BY uid ORDER BY _id) as type,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY uid) as cnt
FROM table 
WHERE type IN ('aaa', 'bbb');
```

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have a "first" aggregation function, but there is a trick if you like:

```
SELECT MIN(_id) as _id, uid,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(type ORDER BY _id), ',', 1) as type,
       COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM table 
WHERE type IN ('aaa', 'bbb')
GROUP BY uid;
```